# FileReader runtime error

Tags: java, text-files, filereader

i trying to slove the problem but still cannot fund the error....

```
 class ReadWriteFile extends Patron{
 static void readFile (Patron p[]){
    try{
        File file = new File("patron.txt");
        int cnt=0;

        FileReader fr = new FileReader (file);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(fr);
        String temp = scan.nextLine();
            while(temp!=null){
                System.out.print(temp);
                String tempPatron[] = temp.split("|");
                String id_codes = Integer.parseInt(tempPatron[0].trim());
                String names = tempPatron[1];
                String S_addresss = tempPatron[2];
                int post_codes = Integer.parseInt(tempPatron[3].trim());
                double overdue_balances = Double.parseDouble(tempPatron[4]);
                String passwords =tempPatron[5];
                p[cnt] = new Patron(id_codes, names, S_addresss, post_codes, overdue_balances, passwords);
            //  System.out.print(p[cnt]);
                cnt++;
                temp=scan.nextLine();                   
            }
    }   catch (Exception ex){
        //ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

what the problem in this error..when i scan inside the text will error by the 1st values....

```
 ? a d | A u n   Z h i   G i e | J a l a n   K e p o n g | 5 2 1 0 0 | 1 . 0    0 | C 1 2 3 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "a"
at         java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
  at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
  at ReadWriteFile.readFile(patron.java:50)
  at Main.main(Testingprogram.java:6)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Integer.parseInt()` on a string that does not represent an integer (line 50 of patron.jave). The error message says the string is "a".